# Animate multiple controls to their positions

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation

Suppose I have a button and 3 buttons behind it. When I click the button, I want the buttons behind it to animate to their positions. I tried to explain it in this picture:

[image: animation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="50">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <QuadraticEase x:Key="AnimationEase" EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="AnimateButton">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard >
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Transform1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" Duration="0:0:0.25" From="0" To="300" EasingFunction="{StaticResource AnimationEase}" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Transform2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" Duration="0:0:0.25" From="0" To="200" EasingFunction="{StaticResource AnimationEase}" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Transform3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" Duration="0:0:0.25" From="0" To="100" EasingFunction="{StaticResource AnimationEase}" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>

    <Ellipse Width="80" Height="80"  Fill="Red">
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="Transform1" />
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    </Ellipse>

    <Ellipse Width="80" Height="80"  Fill="Green">
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="Transform2" />
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    </Ellipse>

    <Ellipse Width="80" Height="80"  Fill="Blue">
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="Transform3" />
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    </Ellipse>

    <Button x:Name="AnimateButton" Width="100" Height="100" />

</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is amazing. One question. If the number of circles is different, is there a way for me to make the numbers automatic instead of hard coding the Y positions? (one thing that comes to mind is to use code-behind).

Comment: It is possible, but that's a completely different question and would have a very different answer. No need for code-behind, you'd instead use an ItemsControl with its ItemsSource set to a list of viewmodels, then specify an ItemTemplate to set the content and animation functionality.

Comment: Alternatively, it might make more sense to use a ComboBox instead with some clever templating.

Comment: I asked a question regarding this, but it got closed so had to make it a bit more specific. Could you please share your code in that question or here?

Comment: Here's the link to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67832003/animate-buttons-from-behind-down-to-their-position

Comment: I added a new question. I even tried to do something from what you mentioned but failed miserably lol. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67858348/run-storyboard-inside-datatemplate-when-an-event-occurs