# Run Storyboard inside DataTemplate when an event occurs

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation, storyboard

I have a ToggleButton and an ItemsControl. The ItemsControl's items have a DataTemplate. How can I animate each of ItemsControl's items, when ToggleButton's check state is changed?

#### The code

In the following code, you can see when the user clicks on the ToggleButton, the chevron rotates. I want the items in the ItemsControl to animate as well. I added a Storyboard with the key "ItemAnimation". I think somehow it should be triggered when the user clicks on the button.

```
<Window x:Class="WinClient.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WinClient"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ShortcutButton">
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="ItemAnimation" AutoReverse="False">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Trans" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" Duration="0:0:0.25" From="-100" To="0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource AnimationEase}" />
                </Storyboard>
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Border Width="100" Height="100" Background="White" CornerRadius="50" x:Name="ContainerBorder">
                <Border.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="Trans"/>
                </Border.RenderTransform>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="50">
        <Border Width="150" Height="150" CornerRadius="75" Background="White" BorderBrush="#FFC12121">
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="Resources/logo.png" />
                <ToggleButton Width="40" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsChecked="True" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}">
                    <Image x:Name="chevron" Source="Resources/chevron-down.png" Width="32" Height="32">
                        <Image.RenderTransform>
                            <RotateTransform CenterX="16" CenterY="16"/>
                        </Image.RenderTransform>
                    </Image>
                    <ToggleButton.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Unchecked">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="chevron" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" From="0" To="180" Duration="0:0:0.3">
                                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseIn" />
                                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="chevron" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" From="180" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3">
                                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseIn" />
                                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ToggleButton.Triggers>
                </ToggleButton>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Shortcuts}"
                      RenderTransform="{Binding Transform}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ShortcutButton}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

#### Update

I want the icons to move from behind the logo to their positions. Meaning the first one would move 100 pixels, the second 200, the third 300, and so on.
Here's what I want in a picture:
[image: animation]

Comment: After adding details to the question, it became clearer.

Let's also clarify: in the initial state, all elements are hidden under the button and are located one above the other.
When you click, each of them "moves" to a separate position.
How to calculate this position?
We need some kind of transformer that determines the end position by the index of the element.
But how do you determine the index?
Is there a property in the element implementation with its index?

Comment: Should the list collapse again on the second click?

Is the number of items in the list not constant?
Are there restrictions on the minimum, maximum number of them?

Comment: According to your XAML, I don't see any styling of ItemsControl at all.
How were you going to implement "blending" of its elements with each other, even if you ignore the animation?

Comment: @EldHasp Yes your assumption is absolutely correct. The position will be the height of each item (let's say 100) plus a few pixels for margin (let's say 5). So the first item moves 5 pixel below the button, the second to 110 pixel below and so on. The number of items is not predetermined so they should adapt. I was thinking maybe a value on ViewModel like the index on the item?

Comment: @EldHasp also yes, the items should collapse when the toggle is switched off. Basically same functionality like Bootstrap's collapse control but with different animation. The styling is just a circle for each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave incomplete code: no AnimationEase resource, no DataContext (ViewModel) code.
Therefore, the implementation example is not accurate.
The example uses the fallback property Tag.
An initial value is written into it and then it is animated.
The transformation of ItemsControl items is bound to this property.
Therefore, they, too, are all synchronously animated.

```
<Window x:Class="WinClient.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WinClient" xmlns:specialized="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Specialized;assembly=System" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="650" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <specialized:StringCollection x:Key="source">
            <sys:String>First</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Second</sys:String>
        </specialized:StringCollection>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ShortcutButton">
            <Border Width="100" Height="100" Background="White" CornerRadius="50" x:Name="ContainerBorder">
                <Border.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform Y="{Binding Tag, ElementName=itemsControl}" />
                </Border.RenderTransform>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="50">
        <Border Width="150" Height="150" CornerRadius="75" Background="White" BorderBrush="#FFC12121">
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="Resources/logo.png"/>
                <ToggleButton Width="40" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsChecked="True" >
                    <Image x:Name="chevron" Source="Resources/chevron-down.png" Width="32" Height="32">
                        <Image.RenderTransform>
                            <RotateTransform CenterX="16" CenterY="16"/>
                        </Image.RenderTransform>
                    </Image>
                    <ToggleButton.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Unchecked">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="chevron" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" From="0" To="180" Duration="0:0:0.3">
                                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseIn" />
                                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="itemsControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Tag" Duration="0:0:0.25" From="-100" To="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="chevron" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" From="180" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3">
                                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseIn" />
                                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ToggleButton.Triggers>
                </ToggleButton>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl"
                      ItemsSource="{DynamicResource source}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ShortcutButton}">
            <ItemsControl.Tag>
                <sys:Double>10</sys:Double>
            </ItemsControl.Tag>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Added in connection with the following clarification:**

> The problem is that when I "uncheck" the toggle button, the circles don't go back to the top. Also, I want the icons to move from behind the logo to their positions. Meaning the first one would move 100 pixels, the second 200, the third 300 and so on.

**MultiConverter for multiplication:**

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace WinClient
{
    public class MultiplicationConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values == null || values.Length == 0)
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

            double product = 1;
            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                if (double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out double number))
                    product *= number;
                if (product == 0)
                    break;
            }
            return product;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public static MultiplicationConverter Instance { get; } = new MultiplicationConverter();
    }

    public class MultiplicationConverterExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
            => MultiplicationConverter.Instance;
    }
}
```

**XAML example:**

```
<Window x:Class="WinClient.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WinClient"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="650" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="source">12345</sys:String>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ShortcutButton">
            <Border Width="100" Height="100" Background="White" CornerRadius="50" x:Name="ContainerBorder">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
        <sys:Double x:Key="zero">0</sys:Double>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="canvasTemplate">
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Style x:Key="itemContainerStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{local:MultiplicationConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                        <Binding Path="Tag" ElementName="itemsControl"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Border x:Name="border" Width="150" Height="150" CornerRadius="75" Background="White" BorderBrush="#FFC12121"
                Panel.ZIndex="10">
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="Resources/logo.png"/>
                <ToggleButton Width="40" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <Image x:Name="chevron" Source="Resources/chevron-down.png" Width="32" Height="32">
                        <Image.RenderTransform>
                            <RotateTransform CenterX="16" CenterY="16"/>
                        </Image.RenderTransform>
                    </Image>
                    <ToggleButton.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Unchecked">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="chevron" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" From="0" To="180" Duration="0:0:0.3">
                                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseIn" />
                                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="itemsControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Tag" Duration="0:0:2" To="0" From="100" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="itemsControlXY" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" Duration="0:0:2" To="0" From="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=border}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="chevron" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" From="180" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3">
                                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseIn" />
                                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    </DoubleAnimation>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="itemsControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Tag" Duration="0:0:2" From="0" To="100" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="itemsControlXY" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" Duration="0:0:2" From="0" To="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=border}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ToggleButton.Triggers>
                </ToggleButton>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl"
                      AlternationCount="{x:Static sys:Int32.MaxValue}"
                      ItemsSource="{DynamicResource source}"
                      ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ShortcutButton}"
                      Tag="{StaticResource zero}"
                      ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource canvasTemplate}"
                      ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource itemContainerStyle}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="itemsControlXY" Y="0"/>
            </ItemsControl.RenderTransform>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Ответ дополнен в связи с дополнительным вопросом:**

> I tried using the Tag for it like this: Opacity="{Binding Path=Tag, ElementName=itemsControl, Converter={StaticResource tagToOpacityConverter}}" but the problem is, I only get the start and the end values of the Tag. Meaning I only get 0 and 100 not the values in between. So the control appears and disappears

Implementation example (changes for the previous code):

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="source">12345</sys:String>
        <sys:Double x:Key="percent">0.01</sys:Double>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ShortcutButton">
            <Border Width="100" Height="100" Background="AliceBlue" CornerRadius="50" x:Name="ContainerBorder">
                <Border.Opacity>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{local:MultiplicationConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Tag" ElementName="itemsControl"/>
                        <Binding Source="{StaticResource percent}"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Border.Opacity>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you. I ran this code. Same issue as Funk's answer. The problem is that when I "uncheck" the toggle button, the circles don't go back to the top. Also, please check the updated question. Thanks.

Comment: Read the supplement to my answer

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I wanted. I'll reward the bounty in 14 hours.

Comment: One question. Suppose I add an Image or a TextBlock or a Border in the `ShortcutButton` DataTemplate.  If I want to animate the opacity of that, what should I do? I tried using the `Tag` for it like this: `Opacity="{Binding Path=Tag, ElementName=itemsControl, Converter={StaticResource tagToOpacityConverter}}"` but the problem is, I only get the start and the end values of the Tag. Meaning I only get 0 and 100 not the values in between. So the control appears and disappears.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you.